# How to click the element with href attribute using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The href is like this:

```
href="../s-reminderNotice.asp?fname=b%2D3c%2DpLessonBooking%2Easp%3Flimit%3Dpl"
```

[image]
I just want to `click()` this text link on a website. My code is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="../s-reminderNotice.asp?fname=b%2D3c%2DpLessonBooking%2Easp%3Flimit%3Dpl"]')
```

Comment: Your image is unreadable. Please include its _text_ into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Booking without Fixed Instructor** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Booking without Fixed Instructor"))).click()
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Booking without Fixed Instructor"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.sidelinkbold[href*='LessonBooking'][onmouseover*='Practical Training Booking']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='sidelinkbold' and contains(@href,'LessonBooking')][contains(@onmouseover, 'Practical Training Booking')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```